# Symfont REST curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8000; No error

Tags: php, rest, symfony, curl

I am learning Symfony REST using this tutorial I found here
http://voryx.net/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-easy-way/

I have gotten to the point where have to make a PUT using this command on my project's root console

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name" : "Test Post", "description" : "This is a test post"}' http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/api/posts
```

When I execute this command above, I get this error on my console

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/brac
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8000; No error
```

Please assist me I am pushing myself to learn Symfony REST

Comment: The link you given say "Make sure to replace http://localhost:8000 with your local domain.". Did you correctly configured your webserver? If yes, change `localhost:8000` by your own `ServerName`, otherwise look at [the web server configuration chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) of the doc.

Comment: I am using wamp server and it launches on localhost. The app is running on localhost wamp server for now

Comment: Yes but not localhost:8000, right ? So if you can access your project by using `http://localhost/yourproject/app_dev.php` , change the url to `http://localhost/yourproject/app_dev.php/api/posts`

Comment: Yes. I thought port 8000 is the default port for the curl

Comment: No, you need to have a webserver that serves your application on this port, follow the link I given you and you'll be ok.

Comment: Okay. I am thinking that this command inserts data into a mobile device via an api right?

Comment: curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name" : "Test Post", "description" : "This is a test post"}' http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/api/posts

Comment: Please educate me I am open to learn and correct my mistakes

Comment: I would like to have the time, but you are coming from too far. You need to understand how work a webserver, that represents more than a 600 char comment  (very much more).

Comment: In which area of application do I have to use this command using real life scenerios>>>>>  curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name" : "Test Post", "description" : "This is a test post"}' localhost:8000/app_dev.php/api/posts

Comment: This comment send a request to your server (Here Symfony2 application). It reproduces the behavior of a client (that can be a mobile application) which sends data to the server (commonly to create a resource). I can't help you more men, you need to understand what is a client and what is a server to play with Symfony (at least).